# Serenity-Cucumber PageObject @DefaultURL no longer getting url from serenity.config file after upgrading to version 3.4.2

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, serenity-bdd

After upgrading my Serenity-Cucumber project to version 3.4.2 I receive this error when running.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid URL: page:signin.url
at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageUrls.verified(PageUrls.java:80)
```

It was working prior to the update and all of my syntax looks correct, I wonder if this feature changed or the syntax changed. After trying to google search around for some answers I have come here.

**Page file**

```
@DefaultUrl("page:signin.url")
public class SigninPage extends PageObject { ... }
```

**serenity.config file**

```
environments {
prod { signin.url = "https://signin.com" }
dev { signin.url = "https://dev-signin.com" }
default { signin.url = "https://dev-signin.com" }
all { admin.signin.url = "#{signin.url}/admin" }
}
```

If I instead change the Page file to contain a static url, that works and I don't get an error.

```
@DefaultUrl("https://dev-signin.com")
```

But, I need it to reference my serenity.config file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some code to directly reference the `serenity.conf` file.

```
@Step("Open sign in page")
public void openSigninPage() {
   EnvironmentVariables variables = SystemEnvironmentVariables.createEnvironmentVariables();
   
   getDriver().get(EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(variables)
       .getProperty(pageObjectFileHere.getClass()
       .getAnnotation(DefaultUrl.class).value()));
}
```

It requires me to pass in an environment variable from mvn command (or will use default)

```
mvn clean verify -Denvironment=dev"
```

It also needs the Page file.

```
@DefaultUrl("signin.url")
public class PageObjectFileHere extends PageObject { ... }
```

And of course the serenity.conf file. (The env passed into the mvn command matches the environments here)

```
environments {
  prod { 
    signin.url = "https://signin.com" 
  }
  dev { 
    signin.url = "https://dev-signin.com" 
  }
  default { 
    signin.url = "https://dev-signin.com" 
  }
  all { 
    admin.signin.url = "#{signin.url}/admin" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using serenity.properties file for configuration. This can be done with the following.

```
webdriver.base.url=http://localhost:1233
```

Then in the default config URL you only mention the remaining part.

```
@DefaultUrl("/mysite/login")
```

Comment: I like the approach. Do you know of a maven command that can set the `webdriver.base.url` in the properties file? Or, some other way to dynamically set it based on the environment you are working in?

Comment: @Alex , I wanted the same but there was no such option. So I handled it manually. 
 Added environment name as a property. Added URLs as env1.webdriver.base.url , env2.webdriver.base.url  . Then programmatically read the URL as per the environment.